# How do you compile different classlibraries to one dll?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compilation

The question explains it all.
I have different class libraries but I would like to compile them into one general DLL.

Is this possible?

I'm using .NET 3.5 with visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See whether ilmerge ([homepage](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) / [download site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en)) does what you want it to:

> ILMerge is a utility that can be used
>   to merge multiple .NET assemblies into
>   a single assembly. It is freely
>   available for use from the Tools &
>   Utilities page at the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Developer Center.

Comment: It would be cool to see this tool integrated into Visual Studio. I am envisioning a check box next to a referenced assembly that you can toggle to control whether it gets merged or is left standalone. Or perhaps a new drop down option along side the copy local option in the properties window. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to build the one dll without source then ILMerge is the best option. Otherwise you can use the assembly linker with a batch file or MSBuild to build the single assembly.

Here's some background info on this
How to: Build a Multifile Assembly - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226t7yxe(VS.90).aspx

Multi-file Assemblies: What and How - http://blogs.msdn.com/grantri/archive/2004/07/07/175745.aspx